# Sublimetext file extension annoyance

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

If I create a brand new sublimetext buffer, then set the syntax of the buffer to something (in this example json).

When I go to save the file, it will have `untitled.json` in the file save dialog automatically. If I then change that to `foo.bar` and hit save. The file saved to my filesystem will be `foo.bar.json`.

Why? My intentions as a user are clear in this case, I'm overriding the file extension for my own reasons.

Is there a way to globally set sublimetext to stop appending what it assumes is the proper extensions to files? Any number of google searches has turned up nothing.

Comment: Set All files in file type